# Use JavaScript var inside of document.formname.inputname.value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

As the title says, I'm trying to use a var inside of a form name.

```
function validate_inventory_form(location){
    var name=document.inventory_+[location]+_input.name.value;

...

}
```

What would the correct syntax be to add the location to the form name so the var `name` would equal the result of `document.inventory_cupboard_input.name.value` for example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document['inventory_' + location + '_input'].name.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access the property, this allow you to use a custom built string as the key.

Something like `document["inv" + loc + "input]`